# Splash Screen Crashing

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am having some problems making my splash screen. It starts quite alright but then goes onto the next activity and crashes after the timed animation. Here is my code:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
final static int DURATION = 2000;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    splashWelcome(DURATION);
}

//Run the splash screen for given time limit
protected void splashWelcome(final int limit) {
    Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                while (waited < limit) {
                    sleep(100);
                    waited += 100;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d("SplashScreen Error:", e.getMessage().toString());
            } finally {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();   
            }

        } 
    };
    splashThread.start();
}
```

}

This is the error:

```
01-10 12:23:57.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19092): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
01-10 12:23:57.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19092): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-10 12:23:57.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19092):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:100)
01-10 12:23:57.835: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19092):     at com.fab.quotes.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:36)
01-10 12:23:57.835: WARN/ActivityManager(114):   Force finishing activity com.fab.quotes/.Main
```

Comment: shouldn't this be Intent i = new Intent(this.class, Main.class);? Did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Main.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `getApplicationContext()` inside a thread.

Try replacing:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main.class);
```

With:

```
Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Main.class);
```

Comment: it worked. great! Meanwhile, why couldn't I use the method getApplicationContext() as it always worked (although I've never called it inside a thread before)

Comment: I think it's because the Application object as well as all other top-level classes like Activity are initialized by the main thread, so accessing them in a seperate thread is going to return null/crash. I can't be certain of that though. I always use `class.this` though as I've encountered several problems using `getApplicationContext()` returning null. You'll see here you shouldn't really be making getApplicationContext calls unless you have to: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext%28%29.